# Visual Studios 2012 Changing Runtime Library causes Link Errors, with C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, linker

I have written program that's uses Fico's BCL C++ library to solve an optimization problem.  When I compile and run the code in visual studio 2012 with the /MDd runtime library, everything compiles fine and the program runs.

I need to be able to run the program on another machine where I cannot install visual studio. When I try to compile my program with the /MD runtime library I get the following link error:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp___CrtDbgReportW referenced in function "public: char const & __thiscall std::_String_const_iterator<class std::_String_val<struct std::_Simple_types<char> > >::operator*(void)const " (??D?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@D@std@@@std@@@std@@QBEABDXZ)
```

When I use the /MT runtime library I get an even longer list of linker errors.

I am new to writing and compiling code in c++ and visual studio. Am I missing something obvious? The Fico software is installed on target system.

Answer (score 1):

These errors mean that you link with the debug version of the BCL library.

In release mode, link with the Release version of BCL.